# Use webpack when including the package.json file fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, package.json, isomorphic-javascript

I am trying to use WebPack to create a bundle for the browser from my *isomorphic* based JS code using commonJS modules. To expose the version in the package.json I do the following in my index.js:

```
var pjson = require("../package.json");
module.exports = {
    version: pjson.version
};
```

However, WebPack will treat the `package.json` file as JavaScript by default, which causes a parser error as it is actually JSON:

`package.json Line 2: Unexpected token :`

I've read that for JSON files, the `json-loader` plugin is required and the module path must be adjusted to `json!../package.json`. While this actually works for WebPack, it will break the code when running it in node.js natively.

So whats the correct way of referencing the `package.json` (or any other JSON file) so that WebPack can create a browser bundle AND not to taint the code with any WebPack-only module paths?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try use as usual:

```
var pjson = require("../package.json");
```

But in `webpack.config.json`:

```
...
module: {
    loaders: [{
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json'
    }, ...]
}
...
```